# Can I shuffle discards into the draw deck?

Tags: exploding-kittens

(Kid-friendly Exploding Kittens for ages 7+)

When the draw pile begins to dwindle down to say 5 or less cards, are we able to combine those few with the large play/discard pile of cards next to it? In other words, let's say there are only 5 cards left face down, and 2 of the 5 are exploding kittens. I'd like to better my odds by combining those 5 remaining cards with the remaining deck and shuffle all of them. Is this allowed?

Comment: Related: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/58368/swap-top-and-bottom-card-in-exploding-kittens

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot shuffle the discard pile back into the deck.
The entire point of Exploding Kittens is that the game eventually draws to a dramatic conclusion where almost all the leftover cards are exploding kittens.

This is supposed to be a short game that you can play multiple rounds of, otherwise a player that is out early in the game would be quite bored.